# Setting an image view's weight and parameters

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I am trying to create a layout dynamically and I am having a small issue.  For some reason I just cant figure out how to set the ImageViews weight.  I looked up this on a tutorial site but when I try to use it I get an error:

LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

What I am trying to accomplish is this (From the Outline perspective):

--LinearLayout (Horizontal) (LL1)

------ImageView (IV1)

------LinearLayout(Vertical) (LL2)

Code that I am trying to accomplish in XML:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/skillOneAbility"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/skillOneImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/skillOneAbilityInfo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```

This is the code I have so far but I am not sure how to set the weight of the ImageView:

```
 private LinearLayout createInnerHorizontalLayout1() {
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //Create the image view and the linear layout with text views
    ImageView iView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    iView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout myInnerVerticalLayout = createInnerVerticalLayout();
}
```

How would I accomplish that XML that I linked up top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .60f);
```

the last parameter is the weight (a float), and having LinearLayout.LayoutParams will fix the error you have with importing the wrong layoutparams